# unable to import passlib in python 3.5.2

Tags: python-3.x, passlib

I am trying to use passlib in python 3.5.2 installed on Windows 8.1.  I installed passlib using :

```
pip install passlib
```

It installed without any issues, but whenever I try to use it

```
from passlib.hash import pbkdf2_sha256
```

I get the error message: *ImportError: No module named 'passlib'*  I am not sure if there are any additional steps to get passlib working?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was accidentally trying to run my script in the 32 bit version of idle instead of the 64 bit version of idle.  My version of windows is 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

First try:

```
pip3 install passlib
```

If it doesn't work, try this:

```
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt
secure = input("password")
print("The secure hash is : " + sha256_crypt.encrypt(secure))
```